# How to simplify a determinant

Tags: matrices

If we have a matrix like:

$A_{12\times 12}=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   {{\Gamma }_{1}} & \mathbf{0_{5\times 6}}  \\
   {{\Gamma }_{2}} & {{\mathbf{G}}_{2}}  \\
   \mathbf{0_{5\times6}} & {{\mathbf{G}}_{1}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right]$

where the matrices dimensions are as follows:

$\Gamma_1: 5\times 6$

$\Gamma_2: 2\times6$

$\mathbf{G}_2: 2\times6$

$\mathbf{G}_1: 5\times6$

is it possible to write $det(A)$ in terms of $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2$ and $\mathbf{G}_1$, $\mathbf{G}_2$?